# Generic Parameters multiple where-clause issue

Tags: c#

I apologize for a weak title, but I have no idea on how exactly to phrase my problem in 1 sentence.

In order to explain my issue, I'm first going to paste my code for better understanding.
I have a class `Generic`:

```
    public class Generic<TObject, ID>
        where TObject : class, Entity<ID>
        where ID : IComparable
```

Now I want to use objects of this class, and its children, as parameters for another class. Something like this:

```
    public class GenericService<TGeneric> 
         where TGeneric: Generic<TObject, ID>
         where TObject: class, Entity<ID>
         where ID : IComparable
```

But the above code gives me an error in the last 2 `where` clauses. Error message says something along the lines of `Cannot resolve symbol TObject/ID`, because I have not put them in the initial generic parameter brackets.

I did a refactor, where `TObject` and `ID` were passed as generic parameters, like this:

```
    public class GenericService<TGeneric, TObject, ID> 
         where TGeneric: Generic<TObject, ID>
         where TObject: class, Entity<ID>
         where ID : IComparable
```

and it works. But I want to avoid writing 3 generic parameters if possible, since those parameters are drawn from the `TGeneric` parameter.

I am attempting this approach because of the following scenario. If I had a class `ChildGeneric`:

```
public class ChildGeneric : Generic<SomeEntity, SomeID>
```

and I want to pass it to `GenericService`, I want to be able to write only

```
GenericService<ChildGeneric> service = new GenericService<ChildGeneric>
```

instead of

```
GenericService<ChildGeneric, SomeObject, SomeID> = new GenericService<ChildGeneric, SomeObject, SomeID>
```

Is there a way to refactor the `2nd code snippet` in order to make it work with the `TGeneric` parameter only?

Comment: "But I want to avoid writing 3 generic parameters if possible, since those parameters are drawn from the TGeneric parameter." -> that's not correct, the compiler cannot know that. The only way to avoid this is to re-think your structure and avoid having so many generics

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, generics are definitely overwhelming, but I am currently working on top of some old code, thus I'm not allowed to change anything that already exists.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you'll need to get used to writing `GenericService<ChildGeneric, SomeObject, SomeID>` then. Unless, of course, you create dummy classes that implement those signatures (such as `public class X : GenericService<ChildGeneric, SomeObject, SomeID> { }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `GenericService` class does not care about the generic arguments of the nested class you can use a non-generic interface:

```
public interface IGeneric
{
    //API for everything you do care for in other classes
    //must not use the TObject, ID types
}
```

just like `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`. Although that may just be for historical reasons.

The downside is having to keep the interface in sync with the class.

If your `GenericService` does care for the `TObject, ID` types, then you need to define them on the class like you did, or specify them in an implementing class as Camilo wrote in the comments.

Comment: In this particular case this was the solution, I added a single-method interface for every Generic I need. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: As a side note I am just now realizing how logical the soluton was, idk how I didn't think of it alone.